# Cant find my js includes

Tags: javascript

Im trying to deploy a website to friends server, but it dosnt include my js files?

I have a very simple folder structure like this

```
MyWebPage:
/Scripts/
/Styles/
default.aspx
```

this is my code:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Coming soon</title>    
       <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.flot.js"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui1-8.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/csspopup.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/renderGraph.js"></script>        
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<% = datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
          });
    </script>

  <link href="/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
<body>
```

The files are there but they dont get included.
However, my CSS get included.

Could it be that the server dosnt allow javascripts? I tried in both IE and FF latest versions. And I tried to go to the URL for the scripts, they are empty but the URL for the css is not.

Anyone know how to solv this? Its running on a 2003 windows server

Comment: Only difference I can see is in the closing tag style. For css, you have used implicit closing tags, whereas for script files, you have used explicit tags.

Comment: @PawanMishra Tried this, dint change anything, the links are correctly writen but the files them self are empty when i click them. If I go to the files in file explorer then they look like they should

Answer (score 2):

The stylesheet you are including is in a folder that starts with a capital S:

```
<link href="/Styles/jque.....
             ^
```

The scripts folder in your code, does not:

```
age="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts....
                                              ^
```

So my guess is that the folders are capitalized but not the URIs in your code.

Comment: I have also tried to follow the URL for the scripts but they just are not there, tried both uppercase and lowercase

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the server is not allowing javascript.  Check permissions on the files and make sure they can be read by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this could be of any help to you but found this piece of information in following article : http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/aspnet/web_c1c.aspx#q508q

"When you install the .Net framework on your web server, it installs some script files (including the above) under the root folder (usually "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" if you do a default installation) . You can then find the above file at "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\1_1_4322", for example.

The above problem could happen if you reconfigured your web root directory to be a different one after you installed ASP.Net in your web server. If that is the case, then run 'aspnet_regiis -c' (utility is under %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322, for example) or copy over manually the above script files into a similar sub-directory below your current web root directory. Also, if you look at the error message in detail, you will notice where the file is supposed to be."

Comment: My folder is not the default web for IIS, its one step further down : "c:\inetput\wwwroot\mywebpage\". Do you still think that might occur?